# PowerShell Invoke-Command asks for type

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, import-module, web-administration

I need to add an application pool remotely and I was trying to use the following:

```
$script = {
    Import-Module WebAdministration;
    New-Item IIS:\AppPools\$IRTPoolName;
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $targetName -ScriptBlock $script -credential $cred -UseSSL
```

The problem is that once I run it I get a prompt with:
`type:`
I don't have any problems with authentication and I can invoke other commands like a simple dir but not that one. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new-item` cmdlet is asking you to specify a type, because it doesn't know what `$IRTPoolName` is.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $targetName -ScriptBlock {
Param($IRTPoolName)
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    New-Item IIS:\AppPools\$IRTPoolName
} -ArgumentList $IRTPoolName -credential $cred -UseSSL
```

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/01/23/pstip-passing-local-variables-to-a-remote-session-in-powershell-3-0/